# A detail in the proof of Poincaré duality

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, on page 246 ([here, in the book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf#page=255)), about two-thirds down the page he states that showing the commutativity of the two squares shown in the diagram, not involving the boundary or coboundary maps, is a 'triviality'.

[image]

I can *sort of* see how it works, but I simply can't work out the details satisfactorily, and all the while the word 'triviality' has been corroding my peace-of-mind like acid rain on a gargoyle. I don't suppose somebody could help me out?